# Qt Serial Port communication

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I am writing a Qt application to communicate with another computer over a serial port. I have 2 real issues.

**1.**
I can send and receive data fine, but sometimes the serial port "eats" part of my input.
For example if I send:

```
cd /application/bin
```

sometimes (not always) it will only receive:

```
cd /applica
```

(Since it's a terminal it echoes the input back. Also my prompt tells me I'm clearly in the wrong spot.)

**2.**
Also, sometimes the Qt slot which fires when there is data available doesn't fire even though I know that there's data I can receive. If I send another `\r\n` down the port the slot will fire.
For example sometimes I'll `ls` something, and the command name will be read back from the port, but the contents of the folder sit there in limbo until I hit return again. Then I get the listing of the directory and two prompts.

Here's my code:

```
void Logic::onReadyRead(){        
        QByteArray incomingData;  
        incomingData = port->readAll();
        QString s(incomingData);
        emit dataAvailable(s);// this is a Qt slot if you don't know what it is.
        qDebug() << "in:"<< s.toLatin1();     
}

void Logic::writeToTerminal(QString string )
{
    string.append( "\r\n");
    port->write((char*)string.data(), string.length());
    if ( port->bytesToWrite() > 0){
        port->flush();
    }
    qDebug() << "out:" << string.toLatin1();
}
```

Comment: I just realized it may not be clear, these are unrelated issues. Shell will tell me that it can't go to `/applica` because no such directory exists

Comment: You'll need to buffer the data that is read from the port until you encounter the <cr><lf>, which might require multiple reads from the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, and I suspect it was an encoding error, but I'm not sure. Instead of sending a QString down the serial port, sending a QByteArray fixed both problems. I changed the `writeToTerminal()` method:

```
void Logic::writeToTerminal(QString string )
{
    string.append( "\r");
    QByteArray ba = string.toAscii();
    port->write(ba);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21698), it appears that sometimes not all the data gets sent, and whatever does gets sent has a '\0' appended to it. So if

> cd /applica'\0'
>   got sent, then the `port->readAll()` would stop there, because it thinks it has read everything.

One suggested answer on that forum was to read line by line, which your code *almost* does. So I think in your case, you can change your code to:

```
void Logic::onReadyRead(){        
    QByteArray incomingData;  
    if(port->canReadLine()) {
      incomingData = port->readLine();
      QString s(incomingData);
      emit dataAvailable(s);// this is a Qt slot if you don't know what it is.
      qDebug() << "in:"<< s.toLatin1();
    }     
}

void Logic::writeToTerminal(QString string )
{
    string.append( "\r\n");
    port->write((char*)string.data(), string.length());
    if ( port->bytesToWrite() > 0){
        port->flush();
    }
    qDebug() << "out:" << string.toLatin1();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to not blindly convert from QByteArray to QString and vice versa without specifying the encoding. E.g. when writing: `QByteArray data = s.toUtf8(); //explicitly convert to UTF-8`; And check return values:`const qint64 written = port->write(data.constData(), data.length());`

Comment: @maditya, I had tried reading line by line but it did not fix my problem. It worked slightly worse than `port->readAll()`
Thanks nonetheless